# Mismatching Types When Pulling Data From an API

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to pull data from this API:
https://epasspeaking.com/api/topics
With this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
    struct Results: Codable {
        let topics: [Topic]!
    }

    struct Topic: Codable {
        var id: Int!
        var topicName: String!
        var trial: Int!
        var order: Int!
        var avatar: String!
        var status: Int!
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://epasspeaking.com/api/topics") else {
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let entries = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
                print(entries.topics)
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
        
        
        
    }


}
```

But I'm getting a type mismatching error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I thought I was putting my data into an array, but it says I'm putting it into a dictionary instead. Why is this happening?

Comment: You have an array but it is the root object, change your decoding to `let entries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Topic].self, from: data)`. Besides that, don't force unwrap all your properties. It's a bad habit and absolutely not needed. Lastly, if you had bothered searching for the error you would have found many similar questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your response data is a direct array so result is not required. Remove Results model and while decode use array Topic.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        
//    struct Results: Codable {
//        let topics: [Topic]!
//    }

    struct Topic: Codable {
        var id: Int?
        var topicName: String?
        var trial: Int?
        var order: Int?
        var avatar: String?
        var status: Int?
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://epasspeaking.com/api/topics") else {
            return
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let entries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Topic].self, from: data)
                print(entries.count)
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```